# sqldeveloper broken autoformat

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, auto-indent

I'm trying to format the following PLSQL code using SQL developer.

```
  log( 'file generated into '
       || 'D:\'
       || 'some path' );
```

SQL developer seems not to like the \' character. From that point on the formatting is broken.

Everything works if I write:

```
  log( 'file generated into '
       || 'D:'
       || '\'
       || 'some path' );
```

Can anyone explain which is the difference between these two codes, and if is there a workaround other than re-writing the code?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The original code is the following:

```
  log( 'file generated into '
       || 'D:\'
       || 'some path' );

  INSERT INTO EXPORT_TABLE (A,
                            B, --comment containing '
                             C)
       VALUES (1,
               2,
               3);
```

And after formatting with SQL Developr it becomes: (note the "C) VALUES" that is now inside a comment )

```
log( 'file generated into ' || 'D:\'           
|| 'SOME path' );      

INSERT INTO EXPORT_TABLE (A,                                
B, --comment containing ' C) VALUES
(
 1, 2, 3
)
;
```

Comment: What do you mean by formatting is broken? Can you execute the code?
I often have the problem, that Toad doesn't understand which brackets belong to each other, but I just ignore that, since I can still execute it.

Comment: Thank you, i updated the question. Unfortunately the code is no more compilable

Comment: I still don't get it. The problem with your last code-snipped is, that `C) VALUES` is part of the comment now.
Do you mean, that some kind of autoformat destroyed your code? If so, than don't use it.

Comment: Sorry for my english, i modified the question. Yes that is the problem. I'm formatting hundreds of packages, I cannot check where the formatting is ok and where the formatting has broken code.

Comment: I think, you just should look for another tool to format your code, if you really need to format it or you just correct the errors your self after auto-formating.

Comment: If you can't compile it, than it is broken.
Sorry, I don't think, there is really a solution that will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses '\' as a ESCAPE character.add an extra '\' to your statement like D:(followed by two '\' symbols).YOU will get the result as follows

```
log( 'file generated into ' || 'D:\\' || 'SOME path' );
```

Hope your Done..

Comment: OK, thank you. However when I write a '\' alone (like from the second code example in the question), sql is correctly formatted. I'm formatting undreads of packages, should I substitute all '\' with '\\' before formatting then?

Comment: No, oracle does not use '\' as ESCAPE-character. You can define you own escape-characters.

Comment: please refer this [link]https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm

Comment: yes @andreav you should.just try replacing all \ with \\.that should be a easy job using an editor

Comment: Do you realize, that he is just formatting packages, that are already working? You need escape-characters just in special cases. Replacing all \ with \\ is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate 'bad idea'? Which cases are dangerous?

Comment: if you write a file and the path is `D:\\location\\file.txt` instead of `D:\location\file.txt` it won't work anymore. I'd really disadvise from using `replace all` for anything, unless you really know, what you are doing.